# Автозапуск php скрипта при старте Denwer

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток! Мне надо, чтобы при запуске denwer автоматически вызывался php скрипт. Возможно это сделать?

Comment: денвер вроде bat-ником запускается. Поправьте его и все. Да и вообще ничто не мешает написать свой батник

Comment: Можно просто его скармливать php интерпретатору, без запуска всяких denwer'ов.